# Splitting flex container into equal width part

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to split content 2 into 2 equal width div that fill the whole content 2 height but fail in doing so. How could it be acheive?

Plunker: [Click here](https://plnkr.co/edit/xTpF7FZXeo1p6g5fYqhu?p=preview)

```
<ion-view title="Welcome">
  <ion-content has-header="true" style="display: flex; flex-flow: column;">
    <div style="height: 100%">
      <div style="background-color: red;">
        Content 1 (height based on content)
      </div>
      <div style="background-color: blue; flex: 2;">
        <div style="display: inline-block;">
          <div style="width: 50%; height: 100%; background: gray;">
            Content 2(part 1)
          </div>
          <div style="width: 50%; height: 100%; background: tomato;">
            Content 2(part 2)
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img style="width: 100%;" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

[image]

Comment: Use a container with ```display: flex``` and assign the width to 50% to the two parts you want to divide.

Comment: @DGA i have updated the plunkr (https://plnkr.co/edit/fTurIO8ERxIUNHNWQwHk?p=preview) but unfortunately it does not take up the full height of the second container div. The height follows the height of the content only

Comment: do you want this? ```<div style="width: 50%; background: yellow;height:400px;">```

Comment: @DGA no i do not want to hard code the height, the height should follow the parent element

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<ion-content scroll="false" has-header="true" style="display: flex; flex-flow: column;height:100vh; ">
    <div style="background-color: red;">
      Content 1 (height based on content)
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: blue; display:flex;flex-direction:row;height:100vh;">
    <div style="flex:1;hight:100vh;">
    content 2 part 1
    </div>
     <div style="flex:1;">
      Content 2 part 2
    </div>


    </div>
    <div>
      <img style="width: 100%;" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
    </div>
  </ion-content>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But it seems to be not working. Can you help in update the plunkr i provider to acheive above effect ?

Comment: i edited your code please check and let me know is this the right one? or should i modify more?

Comment: Hi, what i intend to achieve is split the container with content 2 text into two div with equal width and 100% height of the container 2

Comment: I have updated an image to better describe the issue

Comment: i think now my code does exactly what you want same width with flex so and if you will fill content in any of one container it will use same height for both the columns

Comment: please explain more if there is something with height

Comment: Hi, it does not. The structure should remain the same as the plunker i shown. But i want to have two div inside content 2 div with equal width. The height of the two div should be the same as the height of content 2. I hope i did explain clearly this time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114910/discussion-between-stackdisplay-and-hiral-suvagya).